# angular $uibModalStack.dismissAll() doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the following controller: when routed into it, I show a modal popup "Wait" with no buttons. While the popup is on, I do an http call that returns data. I want to close the popup somehow at this point, no buttons. I've tried a variety of things without a success. My experiments gave me these 2 no-error options:

```
        $scope.popup.close('a');
        $uibModalStack.dismissAll();
```

Unfortunately they don't work, the popup remains to be on. Much appreciate some help here. Here is what I have for the controller:

```
app.controller('PreviewCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $log, $location, $injector, $uibModal, $uibModalStack, cropService) {
    var service = $injector.get('previewImageService');
    $scope.crop = service.getProperty();
    $log.info("PreviewCtrl   --ln 1353 crop:", $scope.crop);    
    if($scope.crop == null){
      $location.path("/edit");        
    }

    var prefix = '${binding.variables.awsCropFolder}'+"/"+$scope.crop.name+"/"+$rootScope.imgName;
    $scope.srcPreview = null;        


    $scope.popup = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,            
        templateUrl: 'progress.html', 
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        size: "sm"
    });//backdrop: "static",

    $scope.getImage = function () {            
        var promise = cropService.getCrop(prefix); 
        promise.then(
           function(payload) {
               //console.log("payload:", payload)            
               $scope.srcPreview = payload.data.src == "" ? null:payload.data.src;                   
           },
           function(errorPayload) {
               $log.error('Promise failure', errorPayload);
           }
        );
        console.log("POPUP", $scope.popup );
        $scope.popup.close('a');
        $uibModalStack.dismissAll();
    };
    $scope.getImage();

    $scope.returnToEdit = function () {
      $location.path("/edit");
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into the same issue - I replaced the modal popup with jquery one: http://dev.vast.com/jquery-popup-overlay/
And it works works! Steps:

```
1) download + install jquery.popupoverlay.js

2) add your popup: 
<div id="my_popup">
    <div class="modal-body" style="background-color:#ffffff;margin:0px 5px 0px 8px;">
        <img height="10" width="150" src="/resources/images/imageTool/progress.gif" alt="Progress Bar"/> 
    </div>
</div>      
3) Add logic to open and close it:
    $scope.getImage = function () {            
        var popUp = $('#my_popup');
        popUp.popup('show');
        var promise = cropService.getCrop(prefix,null); 
        promise.then(
           function(payload) {
               //console.log("payload:", payload)            
               $scope.srcPreview = payload.data.src_1 == "" ? null:payload.data.src_1;
               setTimeout(function (){popUp.popup('hide')}, 4500);
           },
           function(errorPayload) {
               $log.error('Promise failure', errorPayload);
           }
        );
    };
```

I'd like to use an angular popup, but for now, what I have will have to do.